# parindent changes mysteriously (plain TeX)

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, plain-tex, parindent

The parindent appears to increase slightly starting with the second line of output.  Why?

```
\def\arc#1#2{\raise3.5pt\hbox{$\frown\atop\textstyle#1#2$}}

$\vec A$\par
$\arc AB$\par
$\triangle ABC\cong\triangle XYZ$\par
$\triangle ABC\sim \triangle XYZ$\par

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: It also may be decreasing slightly from the 2nd to 3rd (and all subsequent) lines, but if so, it appears to not quite return all the way back to the value on the 1st line.

Comment: I think it's only the second line, i.e. your `\arc` introduces a little bit of horizontal space. Try e.g. `$\vec A$\par $\arc AB$\par  $\vec A$\par`.

Comment: The problem had an easy fix...I just redefined a macro locally to include a small hskip for the rest of the page (the code here is just a very whittled-down MWE that preserved the behavior).  The only reason I posted was to see if anyone knows what causes the rightward shift.  Still have no idea why a little bit of horizontal space in one paragraph would cause all subsequent paragraphs to indent further right too.

Comment: I see no extra space for subsequent paragraphs with your code. It's only the paragraph with the `\arc`.

Comment: `\parindent` isn't changing, but `\arc` is introducing  an extra kern to the left

Comment: As @TorbjørnT.  has already observed, the indentation issue occurs only in the second line. (The value of `\parindent` is not changing.) Your somewhat, ahem, unconventional usage of `\atop` is what's causing the issue: Like `\over`, `\atop` inserts a bit of whitespace both to the left and to the right of its arguments. Just out of curiosity: is there a (good) reason for using `\atop` the way you are doing here?

Comment: Okay after closer inspection I see that everyone's right, it's only the second line (in all cases).  It's the `\atop` inserting the whitespace.  It sticks out more because of the shape of the letter "A".  Sorry about the confusion...thanks everyone.

Comment: Tried a few other ways to get the arc symbol above the AB but they all were adding horizontal space.  Will change my hskip fix to only apply to that one line.  (Should have taken a closer look before posting here...was convinced the whole rest of the page was indenting further right.)

Comment: I assume your last comment was for Mico? You should write @Mico, that way he is notified of the comment. (You as the owner of the post are notified of all comments.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes my last two comments above referred/responded to Mico's comment.  Thank you for notifying and for reminding me to in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\atop` introduces a thin space on either side. You could add `\!` on either side, but probably using a specific math accent is better.

```
\font\yhex=yhcmex10
\newfam\yhexfam
\textfont\yhexfam\yhex
\def\arc{\mathaccent"0\the\yhexfam F3 }


$\vec{A}$\par
$\arc{AB}$\par
$\triangle ABC\cong\triangle XYZ$\par
$\triangle ABC\sim \triangle XYZ$\par

\bye
```

[image]

If you want to use `\frown`, do it differently:

```
\def\arc#1{\mathord{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr$\scriptstyle\frown$\cr$#1$\cr}%
  }%
}}

$\vec{A}$\par
$\arc{AB}$\par
$\triangle ABC\cong\triangle XYZ$\par
$\triangle ABC\sim \triangle XYZ$\par

\bye
```

[image]